# How to include a (matrix) constraint using statsmodels DynamicFactor? python

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using tsa.DynamicFactor of statsmodels with multiple Factors. I would like to include some contraints that impose that some factors can affect only some series. How can I do that?

I couldn't find anything online.
thanks a lot!
Best

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DynamicFactor` you need to use [DynamicFactorMQ](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor_mq.DynamicFactorMQ.html) which allows to specify which observed variables load on which factors via a combination of `factors`, `factor_orders` and `factor_multiplicities` arguments. The docs have some usage examples.